# splongoperation and executiontimeout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-server

Does `SPLongOperation` overrides setting of `executionTimeout` in layouts/web.config for 
sharepoint 2010 standalone/farm and 2013 standalone?

As I have a long running process which works fine in a standalone SharePoint 2010 farm and a standalone 2013 Farm. But does not work as expected in a 2013 farm environment where `SPLongOperation` does not seem to override the `Web.config` `executionTimeout` and a thread abort exception is thrown. Even when the process is running inside `SPLongOperation`.

Comment: Where does it not work ? Because you say it works both on 2010 and 2013 :)? Or is the difference in Farm vs single server install?

Comment: sp2013 farm environment .it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the settings on IIS

IIS -> Application Pool -> Advanced Settings -> Process Model -> Shutdown Time Limit (seconds)

Comment: any difference from sharepoint 2010 environment as it works as expected there?

Comment: I had this problem on Central Administration site, and I had to change the application pool timeout. All the other ways fail.

Comment: this is on sharepoint site and it works perfectly on sharepoint 2010 with same iis settings.only fails on sp2013 farm environment.